# How to send the file in send mail task in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sendmail, email-attachments

How to send the file in send mail task in azure pipeline. I have a folder that contains the multiple .HTML files  with time stamp. Now I want to sent the latest HTML report with the latest timestamp. But I'm facing  issue

List of generated report files in the pipeline

[image: 1]

```
- task: SendEmail@1
  inputs:
    To: ''
    CC: ''
    From: ''
    Subject: 'Email Report'
    Body: 'Please Find the attachement'
    BodyAsHtml: false
    AddAttachment: true
    SmtpPort: '587'
    Attachment: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target/Extent-Reports/*.html'
    SmtpServer: ''
    SmtpUsername: ''
    SmtpPassword: ''
    UseSSL: true
```

The Task is looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

Run a script task before this that sets a variable containing the path to the latest report. Then use the variable to attach the correct attachment.

```
- powershell: |
    $latestReport = (dir index_*PM.html | sort-object name -Descending | select-object -first 1).FullName
    write-console "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Attachment;]$latestReport"

- task: SendEmail@1
  inputs:
    AddAttachment: true
    Attachment: '$(Attachment)'
```